# RowVersion implementation on Entity Framework for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, optimistic-concurrency, rowversion

I am using Entity Framework 6 with PostgreSQL.
I have an entity in which I want to prevent concurrency issues, following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) I added a RowVersion property with [Timestamp] attribute, however after saving changes to the entity the column RowVersion value stays the same in the database.

```
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

Am I missing something or is there another way to handle it in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I finally changed the byte[] RowVersion property for a string xmin property, specific to PostgreSQL, with ConcurrencyCheck decorator.

Comment: can you post the column definition? do you use npgsql to create the model? thanx

Comment: I've just posted the column definition as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
/// <summary>
/// Meant to validate concurrency en database update
/// This column is updates itself in database and only works in postgresql
/// </summary>
[ConcurrencyCheck]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
//[NotMapped]
public string xmin { get; set; }
```

Had to add [NotMapped] attribute just for the column not to be added in the migration, commented it after database-update.

Comment: Thank you. Do you do this in a partial class? I am in a "database first" scenario

Comment: hi there, just remove the setter of the xmin property, instead of using the [NotMapped] attribute. it should not be migrated.

Answer (score 10):

Just an updated answer for EF Core in case anyone else wanders here.

The [Npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org) framework has built-in support for this using the hidden system column *xmin* that the OP is using in his entity as a `NotMapped` property.

As referenced [here](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/concurrency.html), you can set the xmin column as a concurrency token within EF by calling the `UseXminAsConcurrencyToken` method on your entity within its `OnModelCreating` method via Fluent API (a Data Annotation is not available at this time as far as I'm aware).

For anyone already using Fluent API configurations, it's as simple as this:

```
public class AwesomeEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AwesomeEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AwesomeEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.UseXminAsConcurrencyToken();
    }
}
```

Comment: really awesome!

Comment: For real, this is great. Magic, even.